# How to make requests object global in python 3?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have two function

```
def func1():
  res = requests.get('https://goole.com')

def func2():
  print(res.text)
```

I want to access res in func2() but as it is local object of func1() it is not accessible in func2(). I tried making it global like " global res " but i am getting error

```
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
```

ThankYou

Comment: That's a very bad practice

Comment: I will be using class as pointed out by @k4ppa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid global variables, instead return the value you want:

```
def func1():
   return requests.get('https://goole.com')

def func2(res):
    print(res.text)

res = func1()
func2(res)
```

Or use a class:

```
class MyClass:
    def func1():
       self.res = requests.get('https://goole.com')

   def func2():
       print(self.res.text)

myclass = MyClass()
myclass.func1()
myclass.func2()
```

If you really want to use them:

```
def func1():
   global res
   res = requests.get('https://goole.com')

def func2():
    print(res.text)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and pointing out that global variable is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the `global` keyword:

```
def func1():
  global res = requests.get('https://google.com')

def func2():
  print(res.text)
```

or alternatively (and hopefully) pass `requests` object as argument:

```
def func1():
  res = requests.get('https://google.com')
  func2(res)

def func2(res):
  print(res.text)
```

remember global variables are considered a [bad programming practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)